# Displaying the selected date value using datatables or flexigrid in grocery crud

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have a mysql table with 3 columns that contain dates.I did all the setup necessary to have grocery to do the `crud` but something conspicuously missing is the  dates i have selected.

For instance,when displaying some data using datatables or flexigrid,the dates columns are blank.

Why is this and how is the problem solved.

Comment: PLease post your database schema and the code you're using.

Comment: In my database table my fields had date fields only.The code was `$crud->columns('id','date_plates','date_status');
   $output = $crud->render();
            $this->_example_output((object)array('output' => '' , 'js_files' => array() , 'css_files' => array()));
   $this->_example_output($output);`